# Jenkins tools vs shell command : Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm testing a Job in Jenkins with Declarative Pipelines, the job is simple it does a maven test.
When I set maven and jdk in the tools in the declarative pipeline, and then I do mvn test, it works everything goes fine.
But when I use directely a shell command this does not work.

Everything goes fine when I do this:

```
pipeline{
    agent {label "linux-slave-01"}
    tools { maven : "Maven 3.2"
            jdk : "oracle-jdk-1.8"    
    }
    stages{
        stage{
             steps{
                 mvn test
             }
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work :

```
pipeline{
    agent {label "linux-slave-01"}
    stages{
        stage{
             steps{
                 sh ("JAVA_HOME = /xxx/xxx /xx/bin/mvn test")
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error :
 `Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher`

Comment: So, is there a stack trace of the error?

Comment: Yes it is in the title, but you're right, I'll add it, the error is: Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with adding the appropriate $M2_HOME to the PATH in jenkins configuration.